# Dynamically building a command in bash

Tags: bash, scripting

I am construcing a command in bash dynamically. This works fine:

```
COMMAND="java myclass"
${COMMAND}
```

Now I want to dynamically construct a command that redirectes the output:

```
LOG=">> myfile.log 2>&1"
COMMAND="java myclass $LOG"
${COMMAND}
```

The command still invokes the java process, but the output is not redirected to myfile.log

Additionally, if I do:

```
BACKGROUND="&"
COMMAND="java myclass $BACKGROUND"
${COMMAND}
```

The command isn't run in the background.

Any clues on how to get the log redirect, and background bits working? (bash -x shows the commands being constructed as expected)

(In reality, unlike this example, the values of LOG and BACKGROUND are set dynamically)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't work because quotes disable the special meaning of `>` and `&`. You must execute the commands which implement these features of the shell.

To redirect, call `exec >> myfile.log 2>&1` before the command you want to log.

To run a program in the background, use `nohup` (`nohup cmd args...`).

Answer (score 24):

You could do it with the `eval` command:

```
eval ${COMMAND}
```

Comment: Beware that `eval` can break if the parameters of the command need quotes.

Comment: I ended up using this answer - however I marked Aarons as correct as it was slightly more complete...wish I could mark them both correct.

Answer (score 19):

`eval` does what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

CMD="echo foo"
OUT="> foo.log"
eval ${CMD} ${OUT}


CMD="sleep 5"
BG="&"
eval ${CMD} ${BG}
```

Comment: Note: `eval` is evil: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048