# Quoting in a bash variable assignment

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Using the following simplified code extract:

```
DIR='a b'
mount_command="./mount.cpfs $loop $DIR -f $OPTS"
sudo $mount_command
```

Executes this line when trace is on:

```
+ sudo ./mount.cpfs /dev/loop0 a b -f -o default_permissions,allow_other,attr_timeout=0
```

But `DIR` is not quoted, and so `a` and `b` are passed as different parameters, rather than the same to `./mount.cpfs`.

**What's the best way to go about creating a command sequence like this, and then expanding it into a later command line?**

Please keep in mind the code example is simplified to the core problem, I'm using `mount_command` in several places with various additions before and after it, and `DIR` is passed in by the user. I've tried several combinations of quoting `DIR` when assigning to `mount_command`, and a primitive attempt at using an array.

### Example Usage of `mount_command`

```
mount_command="./mount.cpfs $loop $DIR -f $OPTS"
case "$MODE" in
    gdb)
        sudo gdb -return-child-result -x gdbbatch \
            --args $mount_command
        ;;
    normal)
        sudo $mount_command
        ;;
    valgrind)
        sudo valgrind --track-fds=yes --leak-check=full --malloc-fill=0x80 \
            --free-fill=0xff $mount_command
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Mode '$MODE' unknown"
        mounted=''
        exit 2
        ;;
esac
```

### Update0

Please test your suggestions, I don't think the solution is straightforward.

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way in bash is to use an array. The array will keep words separated that are meant to be separated and keep spaces inside individual words:

```
DIR='a b'
mount_command=(./mount.cpfs $loop "$DIR" -f $OPTS)
sudo "${mount_command[@]}"
```

When `"${mount_command[@]}"` is expanded, each element is expanded as a single argument to `sudo` even if it has spaces.

Note how I quoted `"$DIR"` but not `$OPTS`, as your `$OPTS` contains multiple words intended to be passed to the mount command as separate words but `$DIR` should be kept together. However, you could make OPTS an array in the same way as `mount_command` and expand it inside the `mount_command` definition as `"${OPTS[@]}"`:

```
DIR='a b'
OPTS=(-o default_permissions,allow_other,attr_timeout=0)
mount_command=(./mount.cpfs $loop "$DIR" -f "${OPTS[@]}")
sudo "${mount_command[@])"
```

Having done lots of building of commands in bash scripts, I find arrays to be far superior to trying to figure out the correct quoting (if possible) to maintain the command in a simple string.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **eval**.

Given the following script, called **test**:

```
#!/bin/bash
# test

echo $1
```

If I do this:

```
DIR='a b'
CMD=."/test \"$DIR\""
eval $CMD
```

It outputs

```
a b
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715591/dynamically-building-a-command-in-bash)

Comment: This works but it's not as awesome as camh's answer. Also it requires putting `eval` on the command using `mount_command`, which is somewhat invasive. Is there a way to do this without using eval on the final command?

Answer (score 0):

```
DIR='a b'
OPTS='-o allow_other,attr_timeout=0'
mount_command="./mount.cpfs '$loop' '$DIR' -f '$OPTS'"
eval sudo $mount_command
```

This should work. It's hard to understand quoting in shell because it's much
different than in other languages.

In you case you need to quote '$DIR' variable (and better all which can contains spaces). This is clear.
But shell interpret strings just one time! You need to instruct it to
reinterpret by using command **eval**. Without **eval**, variable $mount_command is
expanded but quoting inside is not processed.

You can read my short article about this:
[White Shell](http://www.cofoh.com/white-shell)

Answer (score -1):

<s>Try</s>

```
mount_command="./mount.cpfs $loop \"$DIR\" -f $OPTS"
```

Try this instead:

```
DIR='a b'
#following line replaces space occurrences with "\ "
DIR=`echo $DIR | replace ' ' '\ '`
mount_command="./mount.cpfs $loop $DIR -f $OPTS"
sudo $mount_command
```

Comment: No this doesn't work: it generates this: `+ sudo ./mount.cpfs /dev/loop0 '"a' 'b"' -f -o default_permissions,allow_other,attr_timeout=0`

Comment: A nice suggestion but I'm not looking for hackery as intense as this :)

Comment: now it'll generate `+ sudo ./mount.cpfs /dev/loop0 'a\' 'b' -f -o default_permissions,allow_other,attr_timeout=0` -- neither quoting nor escaping is parsed when word-splitting expanded variables, so there's nothing you can do in the variable itself to keep "a b" from being parsed as multiple words.  I'll repeat Dennis Williamson's recommendation to read [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).