# Quoting space in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, quotes

I have a script which needs to pass a string containing a space.

Basically, I want to collect the error return of calling `curl "https://my-api.com" -H'X-API-Key: API key here'`

The following works, but I'd really rather avoid using eval. I'm sure there is a cleaner way of writing this, but I can't find it.

```
    CURL="curl -s --fail $URL -H\"X-API-Key:$API_KEY\""
    return $(eval "$CURL" >> /dev/null)
```

Comment: `curl -s --fail "$URL" -H"X-API-Key:$API_KEY" > /dev/null ; return $?;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically building a command in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715591/dynamically-building-a-command-in-bash)

Comment: I like this as an answer. Lea Gris's array answer is more general and very elegant, but this simple approach worked for me and I find it a bit more readable.

Answer (score 3):

This is a duplicate of [Dynamically building a command in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715591/dynamically-building-a-command-in-bash), but here is the fix for your code.

Please take the time to read the answers from the parent question.

```sh
# Build the curl command with its arguments in an array
curl_cmd=(curl -s --fail "$URL" -H "X-API-Key:$API_KEY")

# Execute the curl command with its arguments from the curl_cmd array
"${curl_cmd[@]}"
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Arrays are my preferred solution here. ;)